# How to decode the unicode char in Java string?

Tags: java, android, string, unicode

In my android project, i need to display a text with a TextView, but i got a very suck issues with the following string. Someone help me, please.

Here is my java string :

```
TRAI floats new paper on \\u0027Net Neutrality\\u0027: Lists disadvantages of zero-rating plans
```

It's display like this in my TextView:

```
TRAI floats new paper on \u0027Net Neutrality\u0027: Lists disadvantages of zero-rating plans
```

I want it to show like this:

```
TRAI floats new paper on 'Net Neutrality': Lists disadvantages of zero-rating plans"
```

What should i do ? Thanks in advance!

Update :

I have already tried with this code, but don't work for me.

```
title.setText(Html.fromHtml(news.getTitle()).toString())
```

And i want a solution for all '\uxxxx' like chars, not the '\u0027' only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
str = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
```

refer [Apache commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

Comment: How to mark your answer as the final ANSWER ? This is another question, haha

Answer (score 4):

Don't double the backslahes:

```java
String s = "TRAI floats new paper on \u0027Net Neutrality\u0027: Lists disadvantages of zero-rating plans";
```

This will have the value:

```
TRAI floats new paper on 'Net Neutrality': Lists disadvantages of zero-rating plans
```

Comment: Yes, i know that, but the string is not under my control, i got the string from the internet, it just comes with double backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("unicode_character");
```

Comment: This is my code, sorry, i should put it into the question.
`title.setText(Html.fromHtml(news.getTitle()).toString())`

Don't  work for me.

Comment: replace double backslashes with single backslash

Comment: Yes, i know that, but the string is not under my control, i got the string from the internet, it just comes with double backslashes.